# Create an new column(s) after melting a DT according to a ref. DT

Tags: r, data.table

I have this melted DT ;

```
      Gene  SampleID     value
1     Gene1 T26        0.06698887
2     Gene2 T26        1.09944463
3     Gene3 T26        3.63930176
4     Gene1 T27        0.84548702
5     Gene2 T27       -1.49075354
6     Gene3 T27        4.61516518
```

and a sample reference DT;

```
     SampleID Batch Disease Infection
1:   T26          1 Control        No
2:   T27          2 Disease       Yes
```

DT I'd like to add columns from the ref. DT to the melted DTs 'on="SampleID"' is following;

```
      Gene  SampleID     value     Batch  Disease Infection
1     Gene1     T26     0.06698887    1   Control        No
2     Gene2     T26     1.09944463    1   Control        No
3     Gene3     T26     3.63930176    1   Control        No
4     Gene1     T27     0.84548702    2   Disease        Yes
```

and so on.  I tried this with `:=` but DT complained that nrow between two DT are not the same.  I've using a 'setcolumn' trick that I learned from the previous question but it is no desirable. I am looking for a DT one liner solution and any help/pointer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below?

```
setDT(df_reference)[setDT(df_melted), on = 'SampleID']
```

Or just `df_reference[df_melted, on = 'SampleID']` if they're already `data.table`s.

Comment: I should've known that the inner-join would work here !!

Comment: Glad it works! Consider accepting the answer if you found it helpful.